# Streaming audio iPhone/iPad app xcode

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode4

Is there a way to make the audio stream in the background instead of using the whole page?

This is what I currently have:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://s6.voscast.com:8550/listen.pls"];
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [player loadRequest:req];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just decided to use PhoneGap

Comment: Bad choice for a native experience. You should have used `AVAudioPlayer`.